SonarQube reporting missing coverage but not clear what is missing
I have SonarQube running on my builds to detect missing code coverage.
My .NET 8 code has a try/catch/finally block. In the Try block I connect to a FTP server using an FTP client and in the Finally block I disconnect from it.

In the SonarQube report, the last line in red says "Partially covered by tests (2 of 4 conditions)"
It doesn't specify what conditions are missing coverage. I have written tests for the happy path and several exceptions that would always go through that line. I have also written a test that makes _client.Disconnect() throw an exception so the execution never goes through the last line and I assert I am not logging the "Finish disconnecting client" text.
Could anyone think of what conditions I could be missing for this specific line?
Alternatively, is there a way in SonarCloud to show exactly what is missing?
